# Show that $\|f_N\|=\|b\|_q$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $p$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents, with $1 ≤ p < \infty$. Suppose that
>   $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that
>   $\sum _{n=1}^\infty |a_n b_n| < \infty$ for any sequence $\{a_n\} \in l^p$. Prove that ${b_n} \in l^q$.

For any $N \in \mathbb N$ define a linear functional $f_N=\sum _{n=1}^N |a_n b_n|$. Note that $f_N$ is a bounded linear functional. I want to invoke Banach Steinhaus theorem, but first I want to show that $\|f_N\|=\|b\|_q.$ I can show that $\|f_N\|\leq\|b\|_q,$ which follows from Holder's inequality. But I don't know how to prove the other direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For any $x$, $\|f_N\| \geq |f_N(x)|/ \|x\|$ (by the definition of $\|f_N\|$.

Take $x=(a_n)$ where  $a_n=\frac {|b_n|^{q}} {b_n}$  if $b_n \neq 0$ and $a_n=1$ if $b_n=0$. Show that $f_N(a_n)=\|b'\|_q^{q}$ and that $\|(a_n)\|_p=\|b'\|_q^{q/p}$ where where $b'=(b_1,b_2,...,b_N,0,0...)$. You can now conclude that $\|f_N\|\geq \|b'\|_q$.

Comment: $f_N(a_n) = \sum _{n=1}^\infty |a_n b_n| = \sum _{n=1}^\infty |\frac{b_n^q}{b_n} b_n| = \sum _{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q = ||b||_q^q.$ Next, $||a_n||_p =(\sum _{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = (\sum _{n=1}^\infty |\frac{b_n^q}{b_n}|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = (\sum _{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{(q-1)p})^{\frac{1}{p}} = (\sum _{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q)^{\frac{1}{p}} = (\sum _{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}\frac{q}{p}} = ||b_n||_q^{\frac{q}{p}}.$ 

Thus, $||f_N|| \geq \frac{|f_N(a_n)|}{||a_n||}=\frac{||b_n||_q^q}{||b_n||_q^{\frac{q}{p}}} = ||b_n||_q.$ Am I right?

Comment: @dxdydz Yes, your calculations are correct.